# I setup WordPress as an app service on Azure. I want to edit locally on my PC; how do I connect the Azure MySql locally?

Tags: database, wordpress, azure-web-app-service

What do I do?
I have connected to Azure via vs code

I have edited my php files; but I cannot run the WP site locally because I don't know how to connect database.

I want to be able to do all my edits locally and push to the live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created `Wordpress + MySQL Flexible Server` .

In `Azure App Service` => `Configuration Section`, All the key-values related to Database will be saved by deafult.

[image]

> how do I connect the Azure MySql locally?

As mentioned in the MSDoc [Use MySQL Workbench to connect and query data in Azure Database for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/connect-workbench)

- We can use `MySQL Workbench` to connect `Azure MySQL` Locally.
- Even you can check the same in the `Azure MySQL DB`.

You will find different options to connect to DB Locally.

[image]

Install the MySQL Workbench latest version and connect locally.

- Setup a new connection by providing the details from MySQL DB.

[image]

- Now you can manage the DB by querying/modifying from here.